# How to define foreign keys in migrations?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

### The Problem

I want to add foreign keys to tables. When I run my **first** migration `create_posts_table` that looks like this:

```php
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index();

    // . . .
});

Schema::table('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')
          ->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

The following error is thrown:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>
> General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table
> `posts` add constraint `posts_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade)

This is caused because the `users` **table is not created yet**, hence the failure to create the users' referencing foreign key on the `posts` table.

### Possible Solution

The solution to this problem would be to add the foreign keys with a new migration **after all of the tables had been created**. However, it seems clunky to me.

### The question

How can I **define the foreign keys inside their respective tables' migrations**, instead of adding them separately with the different migration after all of the tables had been created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform multiple migrations in the same migration file. If you have a posts table where you want a foreign key to the users table, but the users table does not yet exist, you either have to do it in the users table migration file after the users table has been created - or you have to do a separate migration, like you said. You can't "save" instructions for later in migrations.

Comment: So, these are the only options?

Comment: Afraid so, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Thanks for an answer

Comment: Just for clarity, migrations are run in the order in which they are created. You will see each migration file has a date/time in the beginning of the filename. Setup your foreign keys in the migration file thats setup after the required tables are created; create a separate migration after all created table migrations are setup, or re-order the timestamps associated with your migration files (though this is not recommended - rather start fresh).

Answer (score 0):

In laravel way is keeping separate migration files for different tables with indexing, primary key & foreign keys.....

> CreateUsersTable

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password', 60);            
        $table->enum('status', ['0', '1'])->default('0');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->nullableTimestamps();

        $table->unique('email');

        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

> CreatePostsTable

```
class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();         

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('posts');
    }
}
```